# OnChange event handler in detached dynamic jquery object begin lost by html()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, onchange

This doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/u8ysa/

This does:

http://jsfiddle.net/u8ysa/1/

Does the `html()` method destroy event handler information ? I need to return the object HTML to another function, that's why I need first version (i.e. no place to append - only concatenate - at build time).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any event handlers are lost when converting the html to a string since they aren't part of of the DOM or HTML code.

The solution is not converting the elements to a string - usually there's a better way to do it, usually one not involving `document.write()`

Comment: I see. In my case I will need to create a dummy container just for making append possible...